# Continuity only at $x_0=0$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Consider the function \begin{align}f: \mathbb{R} &\longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \\ x: & \longmapsto \begin{cases} x, \ x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0, \ x \notin \mathbb{Q} \end{cases} \end{align}
>   and show that it is only continuous at $0$

There are multiply analogous questions on math.SE about this function but since it is for a homework assignment and I am given some hints, I would appreciate to work with them.

I did already manage to show that $f$ is continuous at $x_0=0$ which was a fairly simple task, however when it comes to show that $f$ is **not continuous everywhere else** things get slightly harder.

**My approach**:

First I did negate the definition of what it means for a function $f$ to be continuous at some point $x_0$

> $ \forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta > 0, (x \in \mathbb{R}\wedge  \ d(x,x_0) < \delta \rightarrow d(f(x),f(x_0))< \epsilon) \tag{continuity} $
>   and negate this statement to: $$\exists \epsilon > 0, \forall \delta >0, (x \in \mathbb{R} \wedge d(x,x_0)< \delta) \wedge (d(f(x),f(x_0) \geq \epsilon ))$$

For my homework assignment I was given the following hints:

Let $ x \in \mathbb{R}, x \neq 0$ and define $\epsilon := \frac{|x|}{2}>0$. Let $\delta >0$.

**(Case 1, Hint)** For $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ choose $x' \in ] x - \delta , x + \delta[ \ \setminus  \mathbb{Q} $.

I rearranged this statement and came up with: $$ x' \in ] x - \delta , x + \delta[ \ \setminus  \mathbb{Q} \iff B_\delta (x') \setminus \mathbb{Q} \iff \lbrace x \in \mathbb{R} \mid d(x,x') < \delta \rbrace  \setminus \mathbb{Q} $$
If I didn't do any careless mistakes, then the statement is equivalent to the Delta-Ball centered at $x'$ that excludes the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$. Because of that I reasoned that since $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ it must be true that $x' \notin \mathbb{Q}$. Because the distance of two rational numbers would still be a rational number, and therefore not in the given set. $$ \implies |f(x)-f(x')|=|x-0|=|x| =2 \epsilon > \epsilon $$
Please **highlight to me** if my attempt was wrong or flawed, I did this all from scratch and it was the best I could come up with.

**(Case 2, Hint)** For $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$ choose $x' \in ]x- \delta, x + \delta[ \cap]x- \epsilon, x+ \epsilon [ \cap \mathbb{Q}$

Here I have absolutely no idea what to do, the given set looks like two concentric balls to me, an epsilon and a delta ball, but I wouldn't know how this 'hint' can be useful for this second case. Any **hints or insight** would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the interval brackets supposed to be facing outwards?

Comment: @shade4159, I am European, here the outwards brackets were introduced as $ x \in ]a,b[ \iff a<x<b$ I have seen this notation $x \in (a,b)$ which is equivalent to the above.

Comment: I had never seen that before. Guess you learn something new every day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

If $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$, then $f(x) = 0$. So if we choose $x' \in (x- \delta, x + \delta) \cap(x- \varepsilon, x+ \varepsilon ) \cap \mathbb{Q}$,

$$|f(x)-f(x')|=|0-x'|=|x'|$$

Comment: I agree with you, it is what I came up with myself. Although to my embarrassment I must confess that I do not understand why. If we choose $x' \in (x- \delta, x+ \delta) \cap (x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ that would imply that $x' \in \mathbb{Q}$ if I am not mistaken, but what does this set exactly represent? It looks like such an odd statement to me and I don't feel comfortable yet with it. Could you elaborate a bit more? (See my opening post for my 'geometric' interpretation of the given set)

Comment: You are on the right track. When you intersect with $\mathbb{Q}$, it makes the set discontinuous.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I believe to understand this now. Would it also be correct to say if $x=\pi \notin \mathbb{Q}$ then each set before the intersection is in $\mathbb{R}$? like $(\pi - \delta, \pi + \delta) \subset \mathbb{R}$ analogous with the other, such that the intersection would turn down to be $\mathbb{Q}$. If that statement doesn't hold, I believe I can visualize it with the set being discontinuous.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes, since $f$ maps from $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It is easier to use the definition

> $f$ is continuous if $\forall (x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subset I:\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=c \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)=f(c)$,

where $I=[a,b]$.