# Continuity from the right or left at $x_0>0$ of $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Determine whether $f$ is continuous or discontinuous from the right or left at $x_0$ when:
>   $$f(x)=\sqrt{x}, x_0>0$$

My understanding:

By definition, $f$ is continuous as $f$ is defined on an open interval (a,b) containing $x_0>0$ and $$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x_0} \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{x_0}, \forall x_0\in(0,\infty)$$

It follows that $f$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$.

.

Now, the question is asking about the continuity "from the right or left at $x_0$".

As $0 \notin D_f$, the function is discontinuous from the left at $0$; but,  continuous from the right at $0$.

.

Is my understanding correct? Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that the $x_0>0$ part of the question is simply saying that you're being asked to consider the left & right continuity of the function for positive $x$ values. I don't think it is restricting the domain of $f(x)$, which has a natural domain of $x \geq 0$. Then the function is left and right continuous at all $x_0>0$.

Comment: Thx for the input. I forgot to mention that the previous problem was asking  to check the continuity from the left or right at $x_0=0$. I did it here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550642/continuity-only-at-x-0-0?rq=1